# I cannot get a list of requests from solidity to javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, solidity

as far as I know I cannot get an array of structs from solidity to javascript, so make individual request for each request from javacript:

```
 const address = context.params.id;
  const campaign = Campaign(address);
  const requestCount = await campaign.methods.getRequestsCount().call();
  const donatorsCount = await campaign.methods.donatorsCount().call();
  // this returns: requests.count 4
  console.log("requests.count", requestCount);
  const requests = await Promise.all(
    Array(requestCount)
      .fill()  // I tried fill(0)
      .map((element, index) => {
        return campaign.methods.requests(index).call();
      })
  );
  console.log("requests", requests);
```

I have 4 requests but I always get only the first request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `requestCount` contains `string` value `4`.

And because it's not a `Number` type specifying the array length, the [Array() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) takes it as **one** element (value "4") of the newly created array.

**Solution**: pass the value as type `Number` to create a 4-item array.

```
Array(parseInt(requestCount))
```

---

Instead of looping through each index, you can also create a Solidity function that returns the whole array

```
function getRequests() external view returns (Request[] memory) {
    return requests;
}
```

and call it from JS

```
const requests = await campaign.methods.getRequests().call();
```